# how to use messages with freemarker in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

In a .jsp I would use:

```
<fmt:message key="welcome.title"/>
```

to display a message from my messages.properties file.

How would I do this with freemarker ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Import Spring Macro

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
```

Then

```
<@spring.message "yourMessageKeyGoesHere"/>
```

**But** you need to register ResourceBundleMessageSource

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

Keep in mind MessageSource **must be called** *messageSource*

Comment: As I remember, You can import a template by default. @Blankman: you can refer to Freemarker documents.

Comment: Nice answer. Use ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource if the property file is not on the classpath.

Comment: How it decides which property file (e.g. Locale) will be used?

Comment: Does not work for me. Returns: "Template not found for name "spring"."

Answer (score 14):

@Blankman

No, you don't have to import this manually in each template. You can set an auto_import property in your freemarker settings as showed below.

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
   ...

   <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="auto_import">spring.ftl as spring</prop>
        </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: i tried the same for spring.ftl via auto-import it gives `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template spring.ftl not found`

Comment: Change to /spring.ftl <prop key="auto_import">/spring.ftl as spring</prop>

Answer (score 3):

Others are fine answers.  Providing java config as example for those that use that.

```
 @Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/WEB-INF/views/", 'classpath:/templates');
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
    configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(map)
    def settings = new Properties()
    settings['auto_import']  =  'spring.ftl as spring,layout/application.ftl as l,/macros/meh.ftl as meh'
    configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings)
    log.info "returning freemarker config"
    return configurer;
}
```