# Spring message from properties file

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In Spring i need to show message in my ftl file. i am using

```
<@spring.message "property_name">
```

and the message comes from my properties file.

i need the mssage like

```
"Message_content_link"
```

the test link will be a url which will point to another page. i tried like

**properties file**

```
message_content=Message_content
message_link=link
```

**ftl file**

```
<@spring.message "message_content" htmlEscaspe="false"><a href="#url_page"><@spring.message "message_link"></a>
```

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022911/how-to-get-properties-in-jsp-files-using-spring-mvc-3) might help you.

Comment: This questions could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154804/how-to-use-messages-with-freemarker-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker now includes the option to expose the Spring Macro Helpers. In your WebMVC config, add `resolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);`

Now in your *.ftl file, you can call `springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code, argsArray, "", escapeHtml)`

You can then just assign this to a shorthand function:

```
<#function msg code args=[] escapeHtml=true>

    <#local argsArray = [] />

    <#if args?is_string>
        <#local argsArray = [args] />
    <#elseif args?is_sequence>
        <#local argsArray = args />
    <#else>
        <#return "" />
    </#if>

    <#return springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code, argsArray, "", escapeHtml) />

</#function>
```

See an example here: https://github.com/edendramis/freemarker-example/